# iOS - Swift 5 - Cannot Delay within Loop

Tags: grand-central-dispatch, scenekit

I am trying to slow a loop down as it executes too fast in a SceneKit scene.  The loop is called from a tap gesture recogniser function.  I have tried the GCD method of inserting a delay using asyncAfter but it seems to have no effect at all.  I can slow it down by inserting a dummy for-loop but I don't think this is a good technique.   Please see code below...

```
for i in 0...geodesic.count-1 {

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
            
            SCNTransaction.begin()
            
            let quatPitch =  simd_quatf(angle: Float(-1.0/6371.0),
                                        axis: simd_float3(x: 1,
                                                          y: 0,
                                                          z: 0))
            
            aircraft.position = geodesic[i].unit * 1.05
            aircraft.localRotate(by: SCNQuaternion(quatPitch.vector.x, quatPitch.vector.y, quatPitch.vector.z, quatPitch.vector.w))
            
            let SCNQuat = SCNQuaternion(quatSun.vector.x, quatSun.vector.y, quatSun.vector.z, quatSun.vector.w)
            termPathnode.rotate(by: SCNQuat, aroundTarget: SCNVector3(x:0, y:1, z:0))
            
            lightNode.rotate(by: SCNQuat, aroundTarget: SCNVector3(x:0, y:1, z:0))
            
            cameraNode.position = aircraft.position.unit*3
            
            SCNTransaction.commit()
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "executes too fast"? What do you want to achieve with this loop? Inserting some kind of arbitrary delay is highly fishy.

Comment: The animation happens too quickly and gets out of sync.  If I put a for-loop from 1 to 2000 it slows it down between each pass of the loop and it displays correctly.  But why does the asycAfter not work ?

Comment: Doesn't SceneKit allow you to queue up animations? (I believe I've seen something like that before). `asyncAfter` doesn't work because you just push every invocation off by X amount but they will still execute immediately after each other since they are all delayed by the same time. I would advice to not delay the loop and look for a way to property enqueue animations in SceneKit

Comment: Thanks.  I will try an alternative approach using SCNAction